# Passing special characters like E acute to JSON webservice using RestTemplate

Tags: json, spring, jackson, special-characters, resttemplate

I am getting data from database and calling the rest json webservice. I am using spring restTemplate to call the webservice. I have added jackson jar which is being used by spring to create json.
However , I face issue when we get characters like latin e with acute É. Jackson don't escape it and passed as it is, here webservice fails at other end gives 500 internal error. I need to pass its unicode like \u0209. 
I tried using the  StringEcapeUtils to convert it , it got converted to \u0209.
But this time `RestTemplate` escapes it again as \u0209 and it got received as \u0209 on the target system.

Target system is another system we cannot change anything there.

My code for restTemplate is :-

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers =
        new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE); //Note Content-Type as opposed to Accept

        HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(myRequest, headers);

        myResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, responseClass );
```

Comment: Maybe the server has problem because your `Content-Type` header does not have `charset` specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the server doesn't know how to interpret what you're sending. Have you tried

```
MediaType mediaType = 
    new MediaType( "application" , "json" , Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) ); 
headers.add( "Content-Type", mediaType );
```

Cheers,

Comment: i will try this but i don't think my issue with resttemplate, it seems to  be issue during serialization into json.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the issue was that my client was not sending the character set . Notice i changed the header where I am passing Content-Type

My new code :-

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers =
    new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE + ";charset=UTF-8"); //Note Content-Type as opposed to Accept

    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(myRequest, headers);

    myResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, responseClass );
```